# Changing the display on a Visual force page

Tags: visualforce, page-layout, tab

I need some help

I have created a tab called “Other” and the content is looking a VF page called “Other Tab”

My VF page is the following ;

```
<apex:page >    
  <h1>Link to : </h1>
  <apex:outputLink value="https://emea.salesforce.com/801/">Orders!</apex:outputLink>              
   <h1>Link to : </h1>
  <apex:outputLink value="https://emea.salesforce.com">SF!</apex:outputLink>      
</apex:page>
```

However when I click on the tab the results go from left to right

For eg 
Link to : Orders!    Link to: SF

Anyway that I can it going down the page 
for eg 
Link to : Orders!  
Link to: SF

Comment: You can simply add <br /> tag after the first `<apex:outputLink />` for a line break

Comment: HI Highfive, 
Thanks for providing this solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`h1` is a block-level element which spans the entire width of the line. You can use CSS to change them to display `inline`.

```
<style>
    h1 {
        display: inline;
    }
</style>
```

However, don't use `h1` tags for things that are not headers. Use `span` tags, or no tag at all.

```
<apex:page >    
    Link to : <apex:outputLink value="https://emea.salesforce.com/801/">Orders!</apex:outputLink>              
    Link to : <apex:outputLink value="https://emea.salesforce.com">SF!</apex:outputLink>      
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Alex Tennant, thansk for posting your solution, given me a heads up